# Should events be tightly packed for gas savings?

Tags: gas, events, optimization

Is there any gas benefit to tightly packing events?

Ex. event(uint128, uint128, uint256) instead of event(uint128, uint256, uint128) saves storage slots when storing, is it similar in events are emitted?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "when storing" ?

Comment: I mean storing as in when a struct is stored on chain (SSTORE).

See: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/internals/layout_in_storage.html?highlight=packed#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage

Comment: Yes but that doesn't make sense in the context of events, events are not stored in storage,  that's why I'm asking what you mean with this

Comment: I was thinking since the gas calculation for events takes into account the data size, it may take into account the ordering of those data types for them to fit in to 32 byte chunks as well.

Comment: no because they are not stored in storage, and they are abi encoded (so padded to a multiple of 32 bytes) , both your examples take the same space : 3 * 32 bytes saved in the transaction receipt (part of the block, not storage)

Comment: Great, that make sense, thanks for the help!